# Usage of the hashicorp's libvault library in c++

Tags: c++, qt, openid-connect, vault

In order to connect to the vault's server, I need to request an authorization url with the client certificate and the client key. From what I see in VaultClient.h, I first need to create a Vault client, but creating the client requires some kind of token, or username/password ...etc, which I don't have. All I have is the client certificate, and the client key. The mount path is at /oidc.

- I tried to create a Client using the TlsStrategy (which takes a certificate and key), but the mount path was set to "cert", which is not enabled.
- I tried to create a Client with the TokenStrategy with random letters as the token, so I can use that client to make a post request, that did not work either.
- I found an HttpClient class, which can make post requests without the need to create a client first, but there was no method that takes a certificate & key, as well as additional arguments

The header library I'm refferring to:

[VaultClient.h](https://github.com/abedra/libvault/blob/master/include/VaultClient.h)